# How to find pairs in 2 vectors per row and count the result

Tags: r

I've got a text file with 2 vectors  (I read them in as data.frame) as an example.

```
x =c(1,2,1,7,5,8) ; y = c(1,2,1,8,4,8)
```

Im looking to find all pairs between 2 vectors. Im currently writing to file 
and using system call:

```
ans11 = system('grep "^1,1" | wc -l ') to get the result.
```

Using grep I use

```
'grep "^1,1" | wc -l '  and I get a result of 2
'grep "^2,2" | wc -l '  and I get a result of 1
'grep "^8,8" | wc -l '  and I get a result of 1
```

How do I do this with R? I would use grep and wc but there must be a way in R to do it with.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
expand.grid(unique(x),unique(y))
```

**Edit:** Since you say count, I assume you are wanting to know how many times each pair occurs. This you can do it as follows:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(expand.grid(x,y))
setkey(dt, "Var1", "Var2")
dt[, .N, by="Var1,Var2"]

#     Var1 Var2 N
#  1:    1    1 4
#  2:    1    2 2
#  3:    1    4 2
#  4:    1    8 4
#  5:    2    1 2
#  6:    2    2 1
#  7:    2    4 1
#  8:    2    8 2
#  9:    5    1 2
# 10:    5    2 1
# 11:    5    4 1
# 12:    5    8 2
# 13:    7    1 2
# 14:    7    2 1
# 15:    7    4 1
# 16:    7    8 2
# 17:    8    1 2
# 18:    8    2 1
# 19:    8    4 1
# 20:    8    8 2
```

Comment: This is what Im looking for!  Where do you find function setkey?

Comment: You'll have to install the package `data.table` using `install.packages(data.table)`. I'll modify the code.